# Stored procedure searching with in from temp table not working when splitting string into temp table

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have tried a few things to make this work but can't get it.

In my stored procedure, I'm trying to split a string separated by commas into a temp table as ints, so that I can then use those values in an `IN` clause.

Here is the part of the stored procedure I'm concerned with:

```
IF @ManufacturerIds != null
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #ManufacturerIds
    (
        ManufacturerId int NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #ManufacturerIds
        SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ManufacturerIds, ',')

    SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.ManufacturerId in (select * from #ManufacturerIds)'--check last tab, so (use temp table)
    DROP TABLE #ManufacturerIds
END
```

What's happening is that when I pass the comma-separated string to the stored procedure, it returns all results and not the results for the two manufacturers I'm expecting.

The string has been trimmed to ensure there is no stray or empty split results.
I can confirm by stepping through my code in visual studio, the comma-separated ids are going into the stored procedure.

```
var pManufacturerIds = _dataProvider.GetParameter();
pManufacturerIds.ParameterName = "ManufacturerIds";
pManufacturerIds.Value = manufacturerIds != null ? (object)manufacturerIds : DBNull.Value;
pManufacturerIds.DbType = DbType.String;
```

Here is the full stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductLoadAllPaged]
(
    @CategoryIds        nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --a list of category IDs (comma-separated list). e.g. 1,2,3
    @ManufacturerId     int = 0,
    @ManufacturerIds    nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --(passed in filters, manufacturerid above will always be null in this case)
    @StoreId            int = 0,
    @VendorId           int = 0,
    @WarehouseId        int = 0,
    @ProductTypeId      int = null, --product type identifier, null - load all products
    @VisibleIndividuallyOnly bit = 0,   --0 - load all products , 1 - "visible indivially" only
    @MarkedAsNewOnly    bit = 0,    --0 - load all products , 1 - "marked as new" only
    @ProductTagId       int = 0,
    @FeaturedProducts   bit = null, --0 featured only , 1 not featured only, null - load all products
    @PriceMin           decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @PriceMax           decimal(18, 4) = null,
    @Keywords           nvarchar(4000) = null,
    @SearchDescriptions bit = 0, --a value indicating whether to search by a specified "keyword" in product descriptions
    @SearchSku          bit = 0, --a value indicating whether to search by a specified "keyword" in product SKU
    @SearchProductTags  bit = 0, --a value indicating whether to search by a specified "keyword" in product tags
    @UseFullTextSearch  bit = 0,
    @FullTextMode       int = 0, --0 - using CONTAINS with <prefix_term>, 5 - using CONTAINS and OR with <prefix_term>, 10 - using CONTAINS and AND with <prefix_term>
    @FilteredSpecs      nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --filter by specification attribute options (comma-separated list of IDs). e.g. 14,15,16
    @LanguageId         int = 0,
    @OrderBy            int = 0, --0 - position, 5 - Name: A to Z, 6 - Name: Z to A, 10 - Price: Low to High, 11 - Price: High to Low, 15 - creation date
    @AllowedCustomerRoleIds nvarchar(MAX) = null,   --a list of customer role IDs (comma-separated list) for which a product should be shown (if a subjet to ACL)
    @PageIndex          int = 0, 
    @PageSize           int = 2147483644,
    @ShowHidden         bit = 0,
    @OverridePublished  bit = null, --null - process "Published" property according to "showHidden" parameter, true - load only "Published" products, false - load only "Unpublished" products
    @LoadFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds bit = 0, --a value indicating whether we should load the specification attribute option identifiers applied to loaded products (all pages)
    @ListItemOnAmazon   bit = null,
    /*@ListItemOnEbay       bit = null,*/
    @FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds nvarchar(MAX) = null OUTPUT, --the specification attribute option identifiers applied to loaded products (all pages). returned as a comma separated list of identifiers
    @TotalRecords       int = null OUTPUT,
    @SearchCode   int = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    /* Products that filtered by keywords */
    CREATE TABLE #KeywordProducts
    (
        [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE
        @SearchKeywords bit,
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @sql_orderby nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    --filter by keywords
    SET @Keywords = isnull(@Keywords, '')
    SET @Keywords = rtrim(ltrim(@Keywords))

    IF ISNULL(@Keywords, '') != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @SearchKeywords = 1

        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
        BEGIN
            --remove wrong chars (' ")
            SET @Keywords = REPLACE(@Keywords, '''', '')
            SET @Keywords = REPLACE(@Keywords, '"', '')

            --full-text search
            IF @FullTextMode = 0 
            BEGIN
                --0 - using CONTAINS with <prefix_term>
                SET @Keywords = ' "' + @Keywords + '*" '
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                --5 - using CONTAINS and OR with <prefix_term>
                --10 - using CONTAINS and AND with <prefix_term>

                --clean multiple spaces
                WHILE CHARINDEX('  ', @Keywords) > 0 
                    SET @Keywords = REPLACE(@Keywords, '  ', ' ')

                DECLARE @concat_term nvarchar(100)              
                IF @FullTextMode = 5 --5 - using CONTAINS and OR with <prefix_term>
                BEGIN
                    SET @concat_term = 'OR'
                END 
                IF @FullTextMode = 10 --10 - using CONTAINS and AND with <prefix_term>
                BEGIN
                    SET @concat_term = 'AND'
                END

                --now let's build search string
                declare @fulltext_keywords nvarchar(4000)
                set @fulltext_keywords = N''
                declare @index int      

                set @index = CHARINDEX(' ', @Keywords, 0)

                -- if index = 0, then only one field was passed
                IF(@index = 0)
                    set @fulltext_keywords = ' "' + @Keywords + '*" '
                ELSE
                BEGIN       
                    DECLARE @first BIT
                    SET  @first = 1         
                    WHILE @index > 0
                    BEGIN
                        IF (@first = 0)
                            SET @fulltext_keywords = @fulltext_keywords + ' ' + @concat_term + ' '
                        ELSE
                            SET @first = 0

                        SET @fulltext_keywords = @fulltext_keywords + '"' + SUBSTRING(@Keywords, 1, @index - 1) + '*"'                  
                        SET @Keywords = SUBSTRING(@Keywords, @index + 1, LEN(@Keywords) - @index)                       
                        SET @index = CHARINDEX(' ', @Keywords, 0)
                    end

                    -- add the last field
                    IF LEN(@fulltext_keywords) > 0
                        SET @fulltext_keywords = @fulltext_keywords + ' ' + @concat_term + ' ' + '"' + SUBSTRING(@Keywords, 1, LEN(@Keywords)) + '*"'   
                END
                SET @Keywords = @fulltext_keywords
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --usual search by PATINDEX
            SET @Keywords = '%' + @Keywords + '%'
        END
        --PRINT @Keywords

        --product name
        SET @sql = '
        INSERT INTO #KeywordProducts ([ProductId])
        SELECT p.Id
        FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE '
        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[Name], @Keywords) '
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[Name]) > 0 '


        --localized product name
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        UNION
        SELECT lp.EntityId
        FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE
            lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
            AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
            AND lp.LocaleKey = N''Name'''
        IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '


        IF @SearchDescriptions = 1
        BEGIN
            --product short description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[ShortDescription], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[ShortDescription]) > 0 '


            --product full description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[FullDescription], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[FullDescription]) > 0 '



            --localized product short description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT lp.EntityId
            FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE
                lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
                AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
                AND lp.LocaleKey = N''ShortDescription'''
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '


            --localized product full description
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT lp.EntityId
            FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE
                lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''Product''
                AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
                AND lp.LocaleKey = N''FullDescription'''
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '
        END

        --SKU
        IF @SearchSku = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT p.Id
            FROM Product p with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(p.[Sku], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, p.[Sku]) > 0 '
        END

        IF @SearchProductTags = 1
        BEGIN
            --product tag
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT pptm.Product_Id
            FROM Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm with(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN ProductTag pt with(NOLOCK) ON pt.Id = pptm.ProductTag_Id
            WHERE '
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + 'CONTAINS(pt.[Name], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + 'PATINDEX(@Keywords, pt.[Name]) > 0 '

            --localized product tag
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            UNION
            SELECT pptm.Product_Id
            FROM LocalizedProperty lp with (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm with(NOLOCK) ON lp.EntityId = pptm.ProductTag_Id
            WHERE
                lp.LocaleKeyGroup = N''ProductTag''
                AND lp.LanguageId = ' + ISNULL(CAST(@LanguageId AS nvarchar(max)), '0') + '
                AND lp.LocaleKey = N''Name'''
            IF @UseFullTextSearch = 1
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND CONTAINS(lp.[LocaleValue], @Keywords) '
            ELSE
                SET @sql = @sql + ' AND PATINDEX(@Keywords, lp.[LocaleValue]) > 0 '
        END

        --PRINT (@sql)
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Keywords nvarchar(4000)', @Keywords

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SearchKeywords = 0
    END

    --filter by category IDs
    SET @CategoryIds = isnull(@CategoryIds, '') 
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredCategoryIds
    (
        CategoryId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredCategoryIds (CategoryId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@CategoryIds, ',') 
    DECLARE @CategoryIdsCount int   
    SET @CategoryIdsCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #FilteredCategoryIds)

    --filter by customer role IDs (access control list)
    SET @AllowedCustomerRoleIds = isnull(@AllowedCustomerRoleIds, '')   
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredCustomerRoleIds
    (
        CustomerRoleId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredCustomerRoleIds (CustomerRoleId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@AllowedCustomerRoleIds, ',')

    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    DECLARE @PageUpperBound int
    DECLARE @RowsToReturn int
    SET @RowsToReturn = @PageSize * (@PageIndex + 1)    
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex
    SET @PageUpperBound = @PageLowerBound + @PageSize + 1

    CREATE TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp 
    (
        [Id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    )

    SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO #DisplayOrderTmp ([ProductId])
    SELECT p.Id
    FROM
        Product p with (NOLOCK)'

    IF @CategoryIdsCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_Category_Mapping pcm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pcm.ProductId'
    END

    IF @ManufacturerId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_Manufacturer_Mapping pmm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pmm.ProductId'
    END
    --filter by manufacturers(passed in filters, manufacturerid above will always be null in this case)
    IF @ManufacturerIds != null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_Manufacturer_Mapping pmm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pmm.ProductId'
    END

    IF ISNULL(@ProductTagId, 0) != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        LEFT JOIN Product_ProductTag_Mapping pptm with (NOLOCK)
            ON p.Id = pptm.Product_Id'
    END

    --searching by keywords
    IF @SearchKeywords = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        JOIN #KeywordProducts kp
            ON  p.Id = kp.ProductId'
    END

    SET @sql = @sql + '
    WHERE
        p.Deleted = 0'

    --filter by category
    IF @CategoryIdsCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pcm.CategoryId IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM #FilteredCategoryIds)'

        IF @FeaturedProducts IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pcm.IsFeaturedProduct = ' + CAST(@FeaturedProducts AS nvarchar(max))
        END
    END

    --filter by manufacturer
    IF @ManufacturerId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.ManufacturerId = ' + CAST(@ManufacturerId AS nvarchar(max))

        IF @FeaturedProducts IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.IsFeaturedProduct = ' + CAST(@FeaturedProducts AS nvarchar(max))
        END
    END
    --filter by manufacturers(passed in filters, manufacturerid above will always be null in this case)

    --select * from STRING_SPLIT(@ManufacturerIds, ',') INTO #ManufacturerIds
    IF @ManufacturerIds != null
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #ManufacturerIds
        (
            ManufacturerId int not null
        )
        INSERT INTO #ManufacturerIds
        SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ManufacturerIds, ',')
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.ManufacturerId in (5,29)'--check last tab, so (use temp table)
        DROP TABLE #ManufacturerIds
    END

    --filter by vendor
    IF @VendorId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.VendorId = ' + CAST(@VendorId AS nvarchar(max))
    END

    --filter by warehouse
    IF @WarehouseId > 0
    BEGIN
        --we should also ensure that 'ManageInventoryMethodId' is set to 'ManageStock' (1)
        --but we skip it in order to prevent hard-coded values (e.g. 1) and for better performance
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND  
            (
                (p.UseMultipleWarehouses = 0 AND
                    p.WarehouseId = ' + CAST(@WarehouseId AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                OR
                (p.UseMultipleWarehouses > 0 AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProductWarehouseInventory [pwi]
                    WHERE [pwi].WarehouseId = ' + CAST(@WarehouseId AS nvarchar(max)) + ' AND [pwi].ProductId = p.Id))
            )'
    END

    --filter by product type
    IF @ProductTypeId is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.ProductTypeId = ' + CAST(@ProductTypeId AS nvarchar(max))
    END

    --filter by "visible individually"
    IF @VisibleIndividuallyOnly = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.VisibleIndividually = 1'
    END

    --filter by "marked as new"
    IF @MarkedAsNewOnly = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.MarkAsNew = 1
        AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN ISNULL(p.MarkAsNewStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') and ISNULL(p.MarkAsNewEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999''))'
    END

    --filter by product tag
    IF ISNULL(@ProductTagId, 0) != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pptm.ProductTag_Id = ' + CAST(@ProductTagId AS nvarchar(max))
    END

    --"Published" property
    IF (@OverridePublished is null)
    BEGIN
        --process according to "showHidden"
        IF @ShowHidden = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            AND p.Published = 1'
        END
    END
    ELSE IF (@OverridePublished = 1)
    BEGIN
        --published only
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Published = 1'
    END
    ELSE IF (@OverridePublished = 0)
    BEGIN
        --unpublished only
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Published = 0'
    END

    --show hidden
    IF @ShowHidden = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.Deleted = 0
        AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN ISNULL(p.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') and ISNULL(p.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999''))'
    END

    --min price
    IF @PriceMin is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.SpecialPrice >= ' + CAST(@PriceMin AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.Price >= ' + CAST(@PriceMin AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
            )'
    END

    --max price
    IF @PriceMax is not null
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (
                (
                    --special price (specified price and valid date range)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NOT NULL AND (getutcdate() BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.SpecialPrice <= ' + CAST(@PriceMax AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
                OR 
                (
                    --regular price (price isnt specified or date range isnt valid)
                    (p.SpecialPrice IS NULL OR (getutcdate() NOT BETWEEN isnull(p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/1900'') AND isnull(p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc, ''1/1/2999'')))
                    AND
                    (p.Price <= ' + CAST(@PriceMax AS nvarchar(max)) + ')
                )
            )'
    END

    --show hidden and ACL
    IF @ShowHidden = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (p.SubjectToAcl = 0 OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM #FilteredCustomerRoleIds [fcr]
            WHERE
                [fcr].CustomerRoleId IN (
                    SELECT [acl].CustomerRoleId
                    FROM [AclRecord] acl with (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE [acl].EntityId = p.Id AND [acl].EntityName = ''Product''
                )
            ))'
    END

    --show hidden and filter by store
    IF @StoreId > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND (p.LimitedToStores = 0 OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM [StoreMapping] sm with (NOLOCK)
            WHERE [sm].EntityId = p.Id AND [sm].EntityName = ''Product'' and [sm].StoreId=' + CAST(@StoreId AS nvarchar(max)) + '
            ))'
    END

    --filter by specification attribution options
    SET @FilteredSpecs = isnull(@FilteredSpecs, '') 
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredSpecs
    (
        SpecificationAttributeOptionId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredSpecs (SpecificationAttributeOptionId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@FilteredSpecs, ',')
    DECLARE @SpecAttributesCount int    
    SET @SpecAttributesCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #FilteredSpecs)
    IF @SpecAttributesCount > 0
    BEGIN
        --do it for each specified specification option
        DECLARE @SpecificationAttributeOptionId int
        DECLARE cur_SpecificationAttributeOption CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [SpecificationAttributeOptionId]
        FROM [#FilteredSpecs]
        OPEN cur_SpecificationAttributeOption
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SpecificationAttributeOption INTO @SpecificationAttributeOptionId
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
            AND p.Id in (select psam.ProductId from [Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping] psam with (NOLOCK) where psam.AllowFiltering = 1 and psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId = ' + CAST(@SpecificationAttributeOptionId AS nvarchar(max)) + ')'
            --fetch next identifier
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur_SpecificationAttributeOption INTO @SpecificationAttributeOptionId
        END
        CLOSE cur_SpecificationAttributeOption
        DEALLOCATE cur_SpecificationAttributeOption
    END

    IF (@ListItemOnAmazon = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.ListItemOnAmazon = 1'
    END
    /*
    IF (@ListItemOnEbay = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.ListItemOnEbay = 1'
    END
    */

    IF (@SearchCode > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND p.RProductId = "' + @SearchCode + '"'
    END

    --sorting
    SET @sql_orderby = ''   
    IF @OrderBy = 5 /* Name: A to Z */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Name] ASC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 6 /* Name: Z to A */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Name] DESC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 10 /* Price: Low to High */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Price] ASC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 11 /* Price: High to Low */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[Price] DESC'
    ELSE IF @OrderBy = 15 /* creation date */
        SET @sql_orderby = ' p.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC'
    ELSE /* default sorting, 0 (position) */
    BEGIN
        --category position (display order)
        IF @CategoryIdsCount > 0 SET @sql_orderby = ' pcm.DisplayOrder ASC'

        --manufacturer position (display order)
        IF @ManufacturerId > 0
        BEGIN
            IF LEN(@sql_orderby) > 0 SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ', '
            SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ' pmm.DisplayOrder ASC'
        END

        --name
        IF LEN(@sql_orderby) > 0 SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ', '
        SET @sql_orderby = @sql_orderby + ' p.[Name] ASC'
    END

    SET @sql = @sql + '
    ORDER BY' + @sql_orderby

    --PRINT (@sql)
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    DROP TABLE #FilteredCategoryIds
    DROP TABLE #FilteredSpecs
    DROP TABLE #FilteredCustomerRoleIds
    DROP TABLE #KeywordProducts

    CREATE TABLE #PageIndex 
    (
        [IndexId] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [ProductId] int NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #PageIndex ([ProductId])
    SELECT ProductId
    FROM #DisplayOrderTmp
    GROUP BY ProductId
    ORDER BY min([Id])

    --total records
    SET @TotalRecords = @@rowcount

    DROP TABLE #DisplayOrderTmp

    --prepare filterable specification attribute option identifier (if requested)
    IF @LoadFilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds = 1
    BEGIN       
        CREATE TABLE #FilterableSpecs 
        (
            [SpecificationAttributeOptionId] int NOT NULL
        )
        INSERT INTO #FilterableSpecs ([SpecificationAttributeOptionId])
        SELECT DISTINCT [psam].SpecificationAttributeOptionId
        FROM [Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping] [psam] with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE [psam].[AllowFiltering] = 1
        AND [psam].[ProductId] IN (SELECT [pi].ProductId FROM #PageIndex [pi])

        --build comma separated list of filterable identifiers
        SELECT @FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds = COALESCE(@FilterableSpecificationAttributeOptionIds + ',' , '') + CAST(SpecificationAttributeOptionId as nvarchar(4000))
        FROM #FilterableSpecs

        DROP TABLE #FilterableSpecs
    END

    --return products
    SELECT TOP (@RowsToReturn)
        p.*
    FROM
        #PageIndex [pi]
        INNER JOIN Product p with (NOLOCK) on p.Id = [pi].[ProductId]
    WHERE
        [pi].IndexId > @PageLowerBound AND 
        [pi].IndexId < @PageUpperBound
    ORDER BY
        [pi].IndexId

    DROP TABLE #PageIndex
END
```

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing just not sure what it is.
Thanks

Comment: @MartinSmith I add the full stored procedure for you

Comment: the `IF @ManufacturerIds != null` is wrong. You need to use `is not null`. but when you fix that there are other issues. You can't drop the temp table until the final SQL has been executed

Comment: Ahh yep now I get ```Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.```, so I guess that part of the stored procedure is now getting hit

Comment: That function requires version 2016 or up and at least Compatibility level 130

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith will look at changing the compatibility level. I also move the drop table to after ```EXEC sp_executesql @sql``` :)

Comment: @MartinSmith is there another way I can accomplish that without changing compatibility level?

Comment: @MartinSmith it turns out I don't need to change compat level, what I originally wanted to do works now ```AND pmm.ManufacturerId in (' + @ManufacturerIds + ')'``` :) Thanks for your help

Comment: That will leave you open to SQL injection. Possibly not the only place in that proc where it is an issue but I don't have time to look for any further places

Comment: @MartinSmith is that because it's not using cast ```CAST(@StoreId AS nvarchar(max))``` like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out.
NOTE: [nop_splitstring_to_table] comes with nopcommerce install sql script.
here is the code for that:

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[nop_splitstring_to_table]    Script Date: 2/24/2020 3:38:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[nop_splitstring_to_table]
(
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(
    data NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)

    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN
        IF @end = 0 
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (data) 
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))
        SET @start = @end + 1
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
    END
    RETURN
END
```

To get this working I utilized that function with an in statement to select everything from a temp table, the string passed in must be comma seperated:

```
SET @ManufacturerIds = isnull(@ManufacturerIds, '') 
    CREATE TABLE #ManIds
    (
        [ManId] int NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #ManIds (ManId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@ManufacturerIds, ',')

    DECLARE @ManIdsCount int    
    SET @ManIdsCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #ManIds)

    IF @ManIdsCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.ManufacturerId in (select * from #ManIds)'

        IF @FeaturedProducts IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @sql = @sql + '
        AND pmm.IsFeaturedProduct = ' + CAST(@FeaturedProducts AS nvarchar(max))
        END
    END
```

Finally AFTER the sql is executed, don't forget to drop the temp table :)
`DROP TABLE #ManIds`